# Expresso store refresh on product removal

Tags: expresso-store, jquery, javascript, ajax, freebie

I'm using Expresso Store as a webshop. In this webshop I'm able to remove an item from my cart. This is my remove button:

```
<input type="submit" name="remove_items[{key}]" class="remove" value="&#xf00d;" />
```

The problem is that I'm using ExpressionEngines Freebie for the URL. Because of this, when I click the remove button, the page refreshes to the URL that doesn't contain the Freebie segments. A small example:

When I am on this page: 
http://colourindisplay.portalserver.nl/nl/webshop/category/ral-boeken/checkout
and remove an item on this page, it'll refresh to this page: http://colourindisplay.portalserver.nl/nl/webshop

I'm trying to find a way to avoid the refreshing or at least refresh it to the right URL (http://colourindisplay.portalserver.nl/nl/webshop/category/ral-boeken/checkout).

Does anybody have an idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If this form goes along the lines of any other EE form, you should be able to set the hidden "RET" input to influence this. Otherwise to avoid redirects you'll need to develop some AJAX methods.

Can you supply the full source of your remove product form? This will reviea the state of the hidden elements and also where the form submits too (may not be relivent but best to check this too), I suspect it submits to an ACTion if the above holds true and its a standard EE from...

Edit: Fortunatly, as you've supplied working links (+1) I was able to confirm the above myself. It does hold the RET parameter, so you should be able to influence this using the `return` parameter detailed here : https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/checkout_tag.html#return_path

If you share your complete form creation / opening tag I can post  a working example too...

Comment: The rerun path parameter is intended for when an order has been completed after the final checkout step to direct the user to a success page not for updating the cart.

Comment: Thanks Justin, I thought this would be the case, this is why I wanted to see the form creation code the OP's using, in case we'd need to create a 'custom' form using `form_declaration`